# minimal rank of the matrix on the picture

Tags: linear-algebra

In an excercise I am asked about a minimal rank of that matrix. "*" are elements that are not equal to ?$0$. I think the minimal rank is 3, am I right? My argumentation is shown on the picture by red parts.

[image]

Comment: It does seem all right to me.

Comment: you can replace the image by $\begin{pmatrix}*&*&*&0&0&0\\*&*&*&0&0&0\\*&*&*&0&0&0\\0&*&0&*&*&0\\ 0&*&*&0&*&*\\0&0&*&*&0&*\\\end{pmatrix}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your argument is just from the red boxes, but here is mine. Call row $n$ by $R_n$.

If the second and fifth columns of $R_4$ and $R_5$ happen to contain opposite values from each other, then $R_6 = R_4 + R_5$ is possible. And obviously $R_1 = R_2 = R_3$ is possible. Thus $3$ is the highest possible minimum rank.

But $R_3, R_4, R_5$ cannot be linearly dependent. Each has a non-zero value in a column where the other two have $0$. Any linear combination with non-zero coefficients would have to be non-zero in these three columns. Hence the lowest possible rank is $3$.